# Multiple call of restartLoader() results in single call of onLoadFinished()?

Tags: android, cursor, loader, android-cursorloader

I call `restartLoader()` multiple times and in my `onCreateLoader()` I save the last `Loader<Cursor>` to the global variable in order to process only the last one in `onLoadFinished()`. However there's always only one onLoadFinished() call for my n calls of `onCreateLoader()`.

How come? Does the manager throw actually processed loader away if another one comes?

And which one is actually processed? The first one, the last one or the fastest/slowest one?

The reason I need this is because in `onLoadFinished()` I check

```
if (loader == mMySavedLoaderFromLoaderCreated) {
    // do stuff, update adapter etc
} else if (loader == mAnotherLoader) { // I have multiple loaders
    // do stuff
}
```

and sometimes after orientation change it won't pass my check.

**EDIT:**

1. First `restartLoader()` creates a new loader with correct id (100)
2. Then I rotate the screen, the loader with id 100 is ok
3. After this I call `restartLoader()` -> `onCreateLoader()` knows about the id 100 but creates a loader with **id = 0**.
4. `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader,...)`'s loader from arguments is the old one with id 100, not the new created one.

**EDIT2:**

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id == LOADER_PRODUCT) {
        /* creating query */

        mProductLoader = new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                ContentProvider.getUri(Product.class, null),
                null,
                query.toString(),
                queryArgs,
                null
        );

        return mProductLoader;
    } else if (id == LOADER_STATUS) {
        mStatusLoader = new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                ContentProvider.getUri(Status.class, null),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        return mStatusLoader;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (loader == mProductLoader) {
        mProductCursor = data;
        mAdapter.swapCursor(mProductCursor);
        mAdapter.setSearchQuery(mSearchQuery);
    } else if (loader == mStatusLoader) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to restart your loaded many times? When you restart a loaded, the previous instance is discarded and it's result is ignored.

Comment: I programmatically check/uncheck some buttons which filter the result and the cursor is restarted after each check/uncheck.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev The problem is that after orientation change the previous instance isn't discarded. I see the old loader in onLoadFinished() but I've created a new one.

Comment: I actually misread you question. I realised this now. `restartLoader()` only creates a new loader, if one with the provided ID doesn't exist. So, if you are using the same ID, you are not creating multiple loaders, just reusing the existing one. After an orientation change, the active loaders will reload their data and send it back to the callbacks, so you can restore the state of your screen. I don't think you need your check at all.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Unfortunately I need the check because I have multiple loaders. Also please read my EDIT in the question above. It looks like restartLoader() has some bug.

Comment: Can you post you `onCreateLoader()` and `onLoadFinished()`?

Comment: @DanailAlexiev See EDIT2

Comment: So, I would suggest you split up your callback logic in two different instances. One for each case you have. Then, when calling `resetLoader()`, you just pass the right instance. I'm pretty sure something funny is happening with those if statements in the `onLoadFinished()`. If you separate the logic it would be a better choice for cohesion, coupling and also a lot more readable.